# Was ist ein griffiges Gegenteil von "mobil" im Kontext IT und Kommunikation?

Tags: single-word-request

*Gefühlt* scheint die Frage irgendwie einfach zu beantworten zu sein, an der Suche nach einem Wort jedoch, das griffig für **Kategorie nicht-mobiler Geräte** steht, scheitere ich. Außer *nicht-mobil* fällt mir nichts ein. Die eher physikalischen Kontexte passen nicht (*fixiert*, *immobil*, *stationär*...).

Frage also: wie lässt sich eine Kategorie, die all jene Gerätschaften beinhaltet, die weder Handy noch Smartphone noch Tablet noch Notebook etc. sind (also schnurgebundenes Telefon, Desktop-Computer etc.), elegant bezeichnen, im vorliegenden Fall als Auswahlalternative zu *mobil*? Möglichst knappe Wortkombinationen wären auch in Ordnung.

Comment: Ich meine, sowas nennt man *Feststation*.

Comment: @Em1: *Feststation* wäre keine Kategoriebezeichnung, sondern ein (IMHO eher ungebräuchlicher) Begriff für eines der Geräte, die in die *fixe* Kategorie gehören.

Comment: 'Die Frage scheint einfach zu beantworten sein' - was willst Du mit ''Gefühlt'' ausdrücken?

Comment: @userunknown: Als ich den virtuellen Karton der *fixen* Geräte beschriften wollte, nachdem der andere schon *mobil* genannt worden war, fing meine Hand nicht wie selbstverständlich an zu schreiben - was ich eigentlich erwartet hätte. *Gefühlt*, in dem Fall *vor* der eigentlichen Aktion der Wortfindung, hätte ich nicht mit einem Problem gerechnet.

Comment: @Olaf: M.E. ein schlechtes Vorbild für alle, die ernsthaft Deutsch lernen wollen. Aber zur Frage: Mir fallen, aber nicht generell für alles, sondern abhängig vom konkreten Gerät die Begriffe "Heim~, Haus~" oder "Büro~" ein. Dann könnte man bezüglich des Gewichts "nicht tragbar" sagen, angesichts eines Steckers "Netzstrom~" betonen.

Comment: @userunknown: Interessante Nebendiskussion - ist es ein *schlechtes Vorbild*, auf sein Sprachgefühl zu vertrauen (das im vorliegenden Fall leider fehlgeschlagen ist)?

Comment: @Olaf: Ich bezweifle, dass es ein Sinnesorgan gibt, um zu erfühlen, ob es ein Wort für eine Sache geben sollte oder nicht. Wenn "gefühlt" aber nicht für sinnliches Fühlen steht, sondern für die Illusion als Gegensatz zu "gewusst", dann ist das durch "scheint" bereits ausgedrückt und eine - in meinen Ohren - häßliche Verdopplung. Aber irgendwer hat die Mode ja aufgebracht, und muss sich was dabei gedacht haben, sonst wäre die Floskel ja nicht so gefühlt beliebt vielleicht scheinbar "Tüttelchen" :zwinker:.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich finde, dass es an "stationär" überhaupt nichts auszusetzen gibt. Vielleicht noch "Tischgerät"?

Comment: *Stationär* hat für mich die Nebenbedeutung, dass es an einem bestimmten Ort angebracht oder mit einem bestimmten Ort verbunden werden muss. Es bedeutet aber imho nicht *reglos*, *fixiert*, ...

Comment: Es hat auch den Touch von *Krankenhaus*, als das Gegenteil von *ambulant* :-) . Es drückt für mich in jedem Fall nicht aus, dass hier eine Kategorie im informationstechnologischen Bereich gemeint ist, zu der PCs und Schreibtischtelefone gehören.

Comment: @Em1: Aber ein schnurgebundenes Telefon ist doch genau das, angebracht beziehungsweise fixiert. Selbst ein festnetz-Telefon mit einem Mobilteil würde ich grundsätzlich als stationär bezeichnen, da es ohne die Feststation nicht auskommt.

Comment: *Tischgeräte* finde ich jetzt allerdings nicht schlecht. *Mobilgeräte / Tischgeräte*. Mal schaun.

Comment: @Em1: Genau diese "Nebenbedeutung" ist ja die gesuchte "Hauptbedeutung". Genau darum geht es ja, nämlich dass das Gerät an einem bestimmten Ort angebracht oder mit einem bestimmten Ort verbunden ist. Wenn das nicht zutrifft ist das Gerät nicht stationär, sondern mobil!

Comment: @Olaf: Mein PC ist kein tischgerät, denn er steht nicht auf dem Tisch, sondern in einem schallisolierten Schrank, 2 m vom Tisch entfernt. Tischgeräte sind meine Tastatur, der Monitor, die Maus und die Lautsprecher.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Und genau das versteh ich eben nicht unter "nicht mobil". Nehmen wir das Krankenhaus, wo man ja stationär behandelt wird. Nur weil dich dort bin, kann ich immer noch mobil sein. Daher "stationär" != "nicht mobil".

Comment: @Em1: Wenn du in einem Spital stationär behandelt wirst, dann hast du ein Bett im Spital und musst dort bleiben. Da kannst dich dann nicht in ein Taxi setzen und deinen Verlangen nach Mobilität folgen. Siehe auch: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationär

Comment: Ein schnurgebundenes Telefon ist im Umkreis von ca. 10m immer noch mobil, aber (so stark) begrenzte Mobilität ist nicht was unter den Begriff Mobilität fällt. Ien nicht-mobiles Gerät ist also durchaus nicht fest an einem Punkt *fixiert* sondern schwach beweglich, aber es bleibt im Wesentlichen stehen (lat. stare), ist als *stationär*.

Comment: +1 für *stationär*

Answer (score 2):

Also, ich finde "Festgerät" ganz gut. Ist auch ein allgemeiner Begriff.

Comment: Nicht schlecht. Einzig, *mobil* und *stationär* sind Adjektive und *Festgerät* ein Substantiv. Dennoch gefällt es mir irgendwie besser. Vielleicht nehme ich als Gegensatzkategorien *Mobile Geräte* und *Festgeräte*.